# cocos2d-x didnt compile with box2d

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, box2d

i cant include box2d in cocos2d-x.
i compile for android using cmake

```
add_subdirectory(MyGame/cocos2d/external/Box2D ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/box2d)

add_definitions(-DCC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION=1)

target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} 
                        cocos2d
                        box2d
                        )
```

this was in one question where it was usefull but for me it gave new errors.

```
CMake Error at MyGame/cocos2d/external/Box2D/CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_library):
  add_library cannot create imported target "ext_box2d" because another
  target with the same name already exists.
```

what i should to do with it? and error was showed twice

Comment: answer is there

Comment: https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos2d-x-didnt-compile-with-box2d/54382/2